# vb6 Label not updating

Tags: vba, ms-access

The code works fine but the label isnt updating

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim totalmytd As Long

totalmytd = 0
Label1(4).Caption = ""

rs.Open "Select Count(*) as mytdTot from dt_table Where [date] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1) And Date()", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

totalmytd = rs!mytdTot

Label1(4).Caption = "YTD: " & totalmytd
```

Comment: Put `DoEvents` on the next line.

Comment: tried with DoEvents but its not woking

Comment: Put this code inside a button click event and then try it. If it works then may be the event or code block where this code exists isn't getting called.

Comment: Where are you particularly using this code?

Comment: If the label isn't at least getting "YTD:" then that line is not getting executed. If you set a breakpoint in this procedure and step through it, what happens?

Comment: You could also try `Me.Refresh()`